# How to extract users longitude and latitude in real time using leaflet

Tags: mobile, geolocation, leaflet, latitude-longitude

I am using Leaflet in a cross-platform mobile app.
I want the user to see his/her movement on the map in real time. 
I also want to hold their longitude and latitude separately as global variables for I need this information to make a calculation later on. 
 
Below is what I have so far:

```
map.locate({
            watchPosition:true,
            maxZoom:16
          });

function onLocationFound(e)
{
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

  L.circle(e.latlng, radius,
    {
      color: 'red',
      fillColor: '#f03',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      radius: 400
    }).addTo(map);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
```

I believe the "watchPosition:true" enables the map to keep on watching the user.
I just could not figure out how to extract the longitude and latitude information .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Leaflet `map.locate` option is just [`watch`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#locate-options-watch):

> If `true`, starts continuous watching of location changes (instead of detecting it once) using W3C `watchPosition` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onLocationFound(e)
{
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
  userLat = e.latlng.lat;
  userLng = e.latlng.lng;
  movingCircle.setLatLng(e.latlng);
  movingCircle.redraw();
}

var userLocation = map.locate
({
  watch:true,
  maxZoom:16,
  enableHighAccuracy: true
});
var userLat;
var userLng;

    enter code here

var movingCircle = L.circle([0,0], 20,
{color: 'red',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0.5,
draggable: true }).addTo(map);
```